# How can I nominate one of my own questions for deletion?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete

Some of my old questions could even be misleading, since they ask about some software or framework that is completely different today, or my own subjective understanding that a question from my account has been irrelevant for many years, or could lead to some misunderstanding about something else. The "obstacle" is usually that my question has been answered and then it usually needs some exceptional reason to get deleted (it would delete the answers and comments as well I suppose). But if the question really is "low-quality" and appears irrelevant for everybody today, even though it was answered and answer got accepted, is there a routine for me to request it to be deleted, or would that be considered some violation of agreement to do it?

Comment: *"How can I nominate one of my own questions for deletion"* - Hm. It's probably best not to consider them yours anymore. How to delete a piece of community property that you brought into existence is more like it.

Comment: But that is simply the wording of it, I mean even if a movie is not copyrighted (many movies do not have copyright, sometimes by mistakes), one may still call it the work of the director or why not? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_in_the_public_domain_in_the_United_States Many films are in the public domain but does that mean that it isn't the director's work still

Comment: @Gimby Also say it to the answer that got 17 upvotes that they are immediately wrong when calling it my question "You delete a lot of your questions"

Comment: I said you should consider it differently, you personally. Doing so makes it easier to reason when you should or should not delete something. How it is phrased in the question and especially the answer does not really matter all that much, it is how you personally choose to interpret the situation that matters.

Answer (score 19):

Hmm. You delete a *lot* of your questions (~28% of the total number asked). I haven't looked into any of the details (i.e., I haven't read any of the deleted questions), but I don't really understand that or why you think it's helpful.

Just because software or frameworks change doesn't mean that the older questions about it are not useful. People still use older versions of things. If your questions are not *clear* and might be confusing to people, then *edit them* instead of deleting them outright.

> The "obstacle" is usually that my question has been answered and then it usually needs some exceptional reason to get deleted (it would delete the answers and comments as well I suppose).

Yes, that's exactly why. Not only have people put time into answering the question, but if the question and/or its answer(s) have been upvoted, then it's a pretty good sign that people have found it useful over the years. Deleting that would be destructive of value. The whole purpose of Stack Overflow is to become a repository of knowledge. If you delete useful knowledge from that repository, that makes the repository a whole lot less useful.

Of course, as you say, there are inevitably going to be exceptions to this rule, but they're a lot fewer and far between than you seem to think. The only questions that would be "irrelevant for everybody today" are those that ask about services (e.g., APIs) that have been permanently shut down—and, even then, that doesn't *always* make the Q&As useless. Just because the Q&As are no longer useful in an obvious way *to you* doesn't make them categorically useless.

At any rate, there *is* one way that you can get the questions deleted, even though the system won't let you do so: raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag on the post and use the space provided to explain *in detail* why you are convinced that the post no longer adds any value whatsoever to the site (or, equivalently—even preferably—why you think it is *harmful* to leave it visible). It would also be a good idea to mention why you are asking a moderator to delete it, rather than doing it yourself. Something as simple as, "The system won't let me delete this, but I think it should be deleted because ..." is fine.

Note that, by doing this, you are essentially requesting that a moderator review your argument(s) and decide whether or not they agree with you. That, of course, means that it's possible that a moderator may disagree with you. Some people are shocked by this; don't be. We aren't offended because you legitimately asked us for help, even if we ultimately decide not to do what you asked. A declined flag on such a request doesn't necessarily mean "you shouldn't have asked"; it might just mean what it says: "declined". (Alternatively, it could mean that you failed to provide adequate explanation/justification for why the post should be deleted, or that you failed to explain why the task required moderator intervention. But if you followed the instructions and/or template given in the previous paragraph, that should not be an issue.)

Comment: A good example is questions from 2014 how to do something in the Unity 3D editor. Reading that answer today has nothing to do with the solution today. For my own questions, many of them are very hard to believe that they are relevant to other people, even less after a long time has gone. That somebody put in time and effort to answer it just to help me and nobody else, may not be a great reason to keep it around, and there might very well be a reason to keep the answer or the reward for the answer without the "stupid question" being there, about a situation with CSS or something like that

Comment: *Nobody* uses old versions of the editor?

Comment: One guy in Iran with a 16 bit computer does so... No but my main point is that I had a lot of questions that seem too specific for only my own problem and would not qualify as relevant to anybody else. Maybe there is an idea of finding out if a very old question from me about CSS ever was relevant after it was answered. I do not believe it was. It is still there for the sake of SO rules and nothing else. It is impossible for me to believe that those questions fulfil the requirement of being relevant to other people than (1) the OP (2) the guy who answered (3) the SO staff upholding the terms

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz - You can delete a question yourself, provided it's not been answered.  However, asking a question and then deleting it, is really toxic behavior.  Instead you should edit the question so it can be answered. If the question has been answered then you won't be able to delete them yourself.

Comment: Having been that one person using an old version of software and having to dig through archive.org to find now deleted answers, please consider how useful it is to have old questions and answers available to people finding themselves dealing with legacy software for whatever reason.